# WPF Binding TextBlock value to display SelectedItem in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` and a couple of `TextBlock` fields.

I want to display the properties of a `SelectedItem` from the `ComboBox` on those `Textblock's`. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu62l.png)

So that when I choose one of multiple user's the properties in the `TextBlock` will update to those of the `SelectedItem`. I have found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493403/silverlight-textblock-binding-to-selecteditem-in-combobox), although it is using silverlight, and does not work entirely.

```
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="0"
                  Height="40"
                  Name="ComboBox" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding UserModels}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding EnteredUserModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                               Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ComboBoxItemTextBlock}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>


        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="0 10 0 10" >
            <Run Text="{DynamicResource firstName}" />
            <Run Text=": " />
            <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </TextBlock>
```

This is what I've tried. I added `Name` to the `ComboBox` so that I can access it's `SelectedItem` in my `TextBlock`. I need to get the SelectedItem.firstname, etc. At this stage i can only access the entire objects.

Am I missing some useful binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show the `FirstName` property of the SelectedItem, just use an appropriate property path, i.e. `SelectedItem.FirstName`:

```
<Run Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedItem.FirstName}" />
```

or, since `SelectedItem` is bound to an `EnteredUserModel` property in your view model:

```
<Run Text="{Binding Path=EnteredUserModel.FirstName}" />
```

---

Setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is not necessary. It has no effect in a OneWay Binding.

Comment: So UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is only required when using TwoWay bindings? 
If i were to update the value in firstname for example? So that it would update in the combobox?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Even then only if you need to change the default value of UpdateSourceTrigger, which is PropertyChanged  for nearly all properties. You often see it in a Binding of a TextBox's Text property, which has LostFocus as default UpdateSourceTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `EnteredUserModel`-Object, because that's the selected item of the `ComboBox`. If you want the displayed text you must bind to the FirstName-Property.

Alternatively you can bind to `EnteredUserModel.FirstName` in your `TextBox`